# JHipster JDL file with entities extending a common entity

Tags: microservices, jhipster

I'm creating a JHipster project with JDL file which includes applications (gateway and microservices) and entities.
For most of my entities, I need 5 common fields: createdAt, createdBy, updatedAt, updatedBy, isActive.
To achieve this, generally, we create a BaseEntity (containing these 5 fields). Required entities extend this BaseEntity.
Is there any way to achieve the same functionality using JDL file in JHipster?
Also, please suggest how to add these 5 fields to all entities in a JHipster project.

My config:
JHipster - v8.1.0
Java - v17
Node - v18.19.0
NPM - v9.8.1